# Aggregate function in group header?

Tags: ms-access, vba, grouping, aggregate-functions, ms-access-2013

I have a really simple recordset by the name of `qryUserFiles`:

> string: [UserID], [ftype]; Long: [fsize]

(records are file-information details of each file in each users' userfolder on the file-server)

I have created a report which lists the sum of [fsize] for each [UserID] by grouping on [UserID] and putting `=Sum([fsize])` in a textbox in the header of the group.  So far so good.  So that shows me the total size of that user's user-share on the fileserver.  (Helpful with respect to both convincing the users to clean up their stuff, and convincing the executives that we need to buy more storage!)

Now the headbanging part.
I want to add, in that same header, various textboxes containing the sum of the [fsize] for various values of [ftype]. So, for example, I'd want the sum of [fsize] for files where ftype="jpg" for each UserID.  (And then another sum of [fsize] for files where ftype="mov" for each UserID, and so on for various 'problematic' file-types!)

I tried putting a

> Dsum("fsize","qryUserFiles","ftype='jpg'")

in the group header, but, as expected, it is looking at the entirety of the 'qryUserFiles' recordset, and giving me the domain-total of size for jpg, not the this-user-total of size for jpg.

I considered trying to add something to the 'where' clause of the dsum function that would include 'this' user as criteria, but how would I refer to 'this' userID, with respect to the grouping-pointer?

Or is there a way easier way to do what I want without going nuts!?  Would this be easier in another query?  I feel like there's a simple, obvious answer just out of reach!

(I'm hoping to avoid brute-force VBA code to step through the table record by record, and calculate the stats with Dsum and add them to a new table.  But if that's how to do this....)

Answer (score 0):

I think - judging from what I read - you just need to let the report do its stuff. You can group on user and ftype - including the totals in the details and the totals in the Group Footer

You definitely should not use a DSum formula

Comment: Hmm, I could group on ftype under userid - but I'm not interested in EVERY ftype, only the 'problematic' ones, like jpg, mov and pst.  How would I filter the ftype group header to only appear for some ftype values and not others?